# How can I resolve the "Could not fix timestamps in ..." "...Error: The requested feature is not implemented."

Tags: linux, build, f#

I have been trying to build a project in F# on Linux that I have located [here on github](https://github.com/Adron/sharpKataStringCalc). It's a basic kata project that I am working on as a demo. However on Linux (specifically Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop) I haven't been able to get it to build yet because I keep getting several issues as shown.

```
Could not fix timestamps in /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/Microsoft.Bcl.1.1.10.nupkg. Error: The requested feature is not implemented.
```

and...

```
Could not fix timestamps in /home/adron/Codez/sharpKataStringCalc/packages/FSharpVSPowerTools.Core/FSharpVSPowerTools.Core.1.8.0.nupkg. Error: The requested feature is not implemented.
```

My first guess is that Paket just doesn't work on Linux for these things, so I suppose I should remove them from the project. But I've heard that some have gotten it to work with this project and I wanted to determine if it is possible to resolve these not implemented issues.

UPDATE: see @forki's comment. I had to run the following updates to get this to work.

```
apt-get install mono-devel
apt-get install mono-complete
```

More details on http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/#usage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is usually a sign that you should update your mono. Older mono versions have issues with their unzip implementation

Comment: Added an update with the specific steps I took to resolve the problem.